# Electrum wallet not restoring with the right address?

Tags: electrum

I have the address and i can see my bitcoins in it. I have the 12 word seed, but when restoring my wallet with it in Electrum the address with my bitcoins isnt included in the ones generated.

I'm a noob at this please help :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an FAQ about this [here](https://bitcoinelectrum.com/frequently-asked-questions/#why-does-restoring-my-wallet-from-seed-lead-to-a-different-wallet). It contains various things you can try.

Another possibility is that the address corresponds to an imported private key. In the past electrum used to allowed you to import private keys into HD wallets. These imported private keys are not restored when you restore from seed. So is this an address of an imported private key?

Answer (score 0):

There are too many reasons for that, you should provide more details, but I'll share some possible reasons:

- your 12-word mnemonic phrase is extended by an extra word (password), To fix there's an option while you are restoring your wallet, you should select and pass in your password.
- *derivation path*, if you were using legacy bitcoin addresses so you should use path 44, Segwit 49, bech32 Segwit 84
- electrum has their own bip39 wordlist, so if you are not importing electrum mnemonic phrase, you should select that option while importing.

Comment: electrum doesn't use bip44 for legacy addresses

Comment: I'm pretty sure they support bip44.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/j4obgt

Comment: that's for restoring from bip39. Electrum doesn't use bip44 or bip39 for it's native wallets. A wallet restored from a native electrum seed mnemonic would not use bip44 derivation.

Comment: That what I exactly mentioned, `electrum has their own bip39 wordlist, so if you are not importing electrum mnemonic phrase, you should select that option while importing.`

Comment: those are separate points so I got confused. you may want to edit it so it's clearer. you only need to select the derivation path if your wallet mnemonic is from some other wallet. if your wallet mnemonic is native to electrum you don't need to do that. btw the electrum dictionary is identical to bip39's. it's just the mnemonic format and derivation path for legacy addresses that's different.